# Damaged / corrupted excel file ~$

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I had a really important excel file saved with a lot of data on a external hard drive. Somebody unplugged the drive from my computer without safely removing the hardware. I was able to recover everything on the hard drive but the most important file on there is now corrupted. The excel file has ~$ in front of it. I have been trying every program possible but nothing has worked. I followed all the tips listed on tons of websites as well.
I have tried the following:
1. kernel for excel
2.libre office
3.stellar phoenix excel repair
4. datanumen excel repair
5. wise data recovery
6. xls data recovery
7. recovery for excel
8. systools excel recovery
9. repair my excel
10. excel fix
11. excel fix toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Office files with names that start with `~$` contain no document data; they just indicate that the corresponding document is in use. Use a file recovery program to retrieve that main file. Personally, I use [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) (it's free; I have no affiliation with its manufacturer) for such things. In the meantime, make sure you don't write to the drive that contains the missing file; that's a surefire way to wreck any chances of recovery.